# Join Query on Entity Classes in ASP.net

Tags: linq

I am having 2 entity classes(Code First Approach)

1]

```
 public class tblDepartment
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string deptName { get; set; }
        public string address { get; set; }
        **public List<tblEmp> empId { get; set; }**
    }
```

2]

```
 public class tblEmp
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string firstName { get; set; }
        public string lastName { get; set; }
        public double salary { get; set; }
    }
```

Now I want to perform join operation on tblEmp.id & tblDepartment.empId 
I am trying This approach:

```
var result = from d in _Context.tblDepartment
                     join e in _Context.tblEmp on d.empId equals e.id
                     select new
                     {
                         e.firstName,d.deptName

                     };
```

But it is showing an error under "join" keyword

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: it is showing an error because "equal operator" can not applied on List<tblEmp> and int...please note I have used "public List<tblEmp> empId { get; set; }" in first class...thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var result = from d in _Context.tblDepartment
             from e in _Context.tblEmp 
             where d.empId equals e.id
             select new
             {
                 e.firstName,d.deptName
             };
```

Comment: it is showing an error because "equal operator" can not applied on List<tblEmp> and int...please note I have used "public List<tblEmp> empId { get; set; }" in first class...thank you